# Should I buy or build a web services forms module for DotNetNuke?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I'm fairly new to DNN.  I need to spin up dozens of similarly skinned sites, all of which have to eventually call a web service that will allow users to submit information.

I want to find a module that will let me point it at said web service, then let me define the workflow (e.g. fill it out over multiple pages?) and select the controls (textbox, checkbox) to fill out a message to post to that web service.

I've seen things like [Dynamic Forms](http://marketplace.dotnetnuke.com/p-350-dynamic-forms27.aspx) and [Enterprise Forms](http://www.longnhi.com/ProductInformation/Benefits/tabid/105/Default.aspx), but I cannot find any information as to whether this is possible.

Anyone know of a module or optional idea that will allow me to do this?  Am I making something like this up? An absence of answers makes me think "I'll just build it..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My experience with DNN modules is that they're rarely an exact fit for a particular technical issue. So I'd try the following

1) Email the people behind the tools you mention

2) Buy them anyway, with source, and learn the architecture of a well structured DNN addin - the time saved with more than repay the cost

3) Make your decision based on that knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Joshua,

I am not aware of any forms modules out there at this time that integrate to a web service.

However, you might want to look at potentially extending an existing module, and simply changing the persistance mechanism for it, rather than a whole custom solution.